# Connect two words from the DB into one so it can be displayed as a proper URL

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am new in Python, I have a problem with the localhost:8000/name entry. 
Names that consist of one word in the DB display ok, words that consist of two words don't display ok.

My browser tells me:

Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$ [name='index']
^admin/
^(?P<book_title>[\w_-]+)/$ [name='detail']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, Crazy dog, didn't match any of these.
```

books/templates/books/index.html

```
{% extends "master.html"  %}

{% block h1 %} 
<div class="box first">
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        {% for question  in latest_question_list %}
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="{{question.title}} " i class="icon-credit-card icon-md icon-color1"></a>
                    <h4>{{question.title}} </h4>
                    <p>{{question.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

```
{% endblock %}
{% block title  %} Index {% endblock %}
```

books/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question


def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()
   context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
   return render(request, 'papers/index.html', context)

def detail(request, book_title):
    question = Question.objects.get(title=book_title)
    return render(request, 'books/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'books.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^(?P<book_title>[\w_-]+)/$', 'books.views.detail', name='detail'),
 ]

 urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the regular expression for your url does not recognise the space character:

```
r'^(?P<naslov_papers>[\w_-]+)/$'
```

You could tell it to accept them:

```
r'^(?P<naslov_papers>[\w\s_-]+)/$'
```

The longer answer is:
If the name such as `"Vozacka dozvola"` comes from a field on a model, then a common approach in Django is to have a second [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) on the model which stores a version of the name with spaces and special chars replaced with hyphens.

When you use a `SlugField` you can tell the Django admin site to automatically populate the value of the slug from the other field on your model:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields